# what is the mistake this code not showing output? i want to display data using repeater

Tags: c#

```
public partial class ADOTEST : System.Web.UI.Page {
     SqlDataAdapter da = null;
     SqlConnection cn = null;
     DataSet ds = null;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Database=TestDb ; Uid=sa ; password=123 ");

         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         {
             BindEmpData();  
         }
     }

     void BindEmpData()
     {
         da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *From EMPLOYEE", cn);
         ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds, "EMPLOYEE");

         Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables["EMPLOYEE"];
         // Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
         // Repeater1.DataMember = "EMPLOYEE";
         Repeater1.DataBind();
     }
```

Comment: What's the question? Please tell us what you expected to happen, and what actually _did_ happen.

Comment: i want to connect to a table in sqlserver and

Comment: i want to display  sql serverdata using repeater in asp.net

Comment: not showing any error just diplaying a blank aspx page sorry for my mistakes im new to stackoverflow!

Comment: breakpoints, and debug! (In my answer I describe what I think is the error)

Comment: Edit your question, don't hide information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your future reference, the following would probably be a better idea:

```
public partial class ADOTEST : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindEmpData();  
        }
    }

    void BindEmpData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Database=TestDb ; Uid=sa ; password=123 "))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *From EMPLOYEE", cn))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "EMPLOYEE");
            }
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables["EMPLOYEE"];
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The `using` blocks will ensure that the resources are cleaned up, even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The conecction string i think is wrong, and the "select" too

```
"*From"

"* From"
```